# Repeated Items in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have created a custom listview with array adapter. It contains a Edittext and some other radiobuttons etc.
My listview shows repeated views after every4 views. I.e hen I type in 1st Edittext it got entered in 5th EditText also.
I have read that , to save memory android creates only limited views and repeats it .
So , how to overcome this problem? How to use bindView() method? and Where? and How?

ublic class QuestionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

```
Context context; 

int layoutResourceId;    
Question data[] = null;

public QuestionAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Question[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    final WeatherHolder holder;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();          
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        //row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, null);
        holder = new WeatherHolder();
        holder.txtquestion = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtquestion);
        holder.radioYes = (RadioButton)row.findViewById(R.id.radioYes);
        holder.radioNo= (RadioButton)row.findViewById(R.id.radioNo);
        holder.editResponse=(EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.editResponse);
        holder.radio_group=(RadioGroup)row.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

        row.setTag(holder);


    }
    else

    {
        holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Question question = data[position];
    holder.txtquestion.setText(question.question);
    holder.radioYes.setChecked(true);
    holder.radioYes.setChecked(false);

    //holder.editResponse.setText("Edit Response");
    return row;

}



static class WeatherHolder
{
    TextView txtquestion;
    RadioButton radioYes;
    RadioButton radioNo;
    EditText editResponse;
    RadioGroup radio_group;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you post your adapter implementation?

Comment: put your code snippet

Comment: @HemantVc plz see the Question/

Answer (score 0):

In getView() you have to assign manually the value for each view, in your case for each EditText. You can do edtitext.setText("") in getView and when you write in one edittext, your listview will not show repeated.

EDIT:

You can try to have an structure for saving the text in each EditText and inside of getView() you assign these text to its EditText

```
String [] text ;

Question data[] = null;

public QuestionAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Question[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;

    text = new String[data.length];

    for(String s: text)
        s="";
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    final WeatherHolder holder;
    final pos = position;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();          
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        //row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, null);
        holder = new WeatherHolder();
        holder.txtquestion = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtquestion);
        holder.radioYes = (RadioButton)row.findViewById(R.id.radioYes);
        holder.radioNo= (RadioButton)row.findViewById(R.id.radioNo);
        holder.editResponse=(EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.editResponse);
        //Add a listener and you'll know the text inside EditText
        holder.editResponse.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //Save text after typed it
            text[pos] = s.toString();

        }
    });

    holder.radio_group=(RadioGroup)row.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

    row.setTag(holder);


}
else

{
    holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
}

    Question question = data[position];
    holder.txtquestion.setText(question.question);
    holder.radioYes.setChecked(true);
    holder.radioYes.setChecked(false);
    //Assign text
    holder.editResponse.setText(text[position]);
    return row;
}
```

Comment: There is a new problem. when I scroll listview up or down ,There is no text inside the EditText. I think saving text to EditText is not working.

Comment: The code that you written in onTextChanged should be in OnFocusChanged. then it Will work fine. Thanks a ton.

Comment: And Yes,  OnfocusChangedLister should not be in if or else statement there. it should be after the else{} block..As you are just inflating a row in if(row=null){} block.

Answer (score 0):

How does your getView(...) implementation look like?

It should be something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View view = convertView;

    if(view == null)
        view = inflate(view, parent);

    MyObject obj = objects.get(position);
    if(obj != null)
        view = setUIControls(position, view, obj);

    return view;
}
```

You either inflate a new `View` or reuse an 'old' `View`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all use ConvertView instead of your VIEW
this is useless, what you'v done with them;

```
if(convertView == null){
convertView=inflater.inflate....



return convertView;
```

then remove `final` modifier from viewHolderObject;

```
Question data[] = null;// what the hell? if you want an array....
Question[] data=null;
```

and make your view holder shared

```
class YourClass..{
private WeatherHolder holder;
```

and when `converView==null`

```
if(convertView==null){
....
holder=new WeatherHolder();
```